# gridstack.js plugin: Is possible to disable horizontal drag (resize) in gridstack.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridstack

I need to disable horizontally dragging or resizing option in my application. I'm using [gridstack.js](http://gridstackjs.com/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found solution for my question. 
There is "resizable" option is there, They providing five options to set resize the widget. 'e, se, s, sw, w'

```
resizable: {
            handles: 'e, se, s, sw, w'
        }
```

If you want to adjusting in **Horizontal only** use below

```
resizable: {
            handles: 'e'
        }
```

For **Vertical only**

```
resizable: {
            handles: 's'
        }
```